ROS2 example : colcon build --symlink-install，error~~
Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2-rolling.
When I refer to https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html to execute colcon build --symlink-install, the compilation error:
/ros2_ws/src/examples/rclcpp/wait_set/src/wait_set_topics_and_timer.cpp: In function ‘int32_t main(int32_t, char**)’:
/ros2_ws/src/examples/rclcpp/wait_set/src/wait_set_topics_and_timer.cpp:76:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::TimerBase::execute_callback(bool&)’
   76 |           one_off_timer->execute_callback(data);
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/callback_group.hpp:30,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/any_executable.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategy.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/memory_strategies.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor_options.hpp:20,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executor.hpp:37,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:172,
                 from /ros2_ws/src/examples/rclcpp/wait_set/src/wait_set_topics_and_timer.cpp:17:
/opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:113:3: note: candidate: ‘virtual void rclcpp::TimerBase::execute_callback()’
  113 |   execute_callback() = 0;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/rolling/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/timer.hpp:113:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wait_set_topics_and_timer.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/wait_set_topics_and_timer.dir/src/wait_set_topics_and_timer.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:341: CMakeFiles/wait_set_topics_and_timer.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2

Failed   <<< examples_rclcpp_wait_set [15.5s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber [16.1s]                                                                                                       
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [18.8s]

What should I do?

Seems like an error with your callback function that you've provided to the timer. Can you share a snippet of the code?

It’s a demo project in https://github.com/ros2/examples. I just did the download and direct compilation action.

I ran into the same error trying to build the examples in a docker container using the rolling/jammy image. When I reverted to the jazzy/noble docker image the error did not occur there.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
